# Loop through a Python list in Django template with for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to simplify this Django template,

```
{{ var.1 }}
{{ var.2 }}
{{ var.3 }}
{{ var.4 }}
{{ var.5 }}
```

var is Python list passed as context to the template

how do you convert the above template using a for tag construct.  I tried this but does not work.

```
 {% for i in var|length %}
     {{ var.i }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
{% for x in var %}
    {{x}}
{% endfor %}
```